# Accessing constructor arguments within a TypeScript Class Mixin

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a class mixin. Within that mixin, I would like to access one of the dependencies injected via the constructor arguments:

```
export type Constructor<T> = new(...args: any[]) => T;
export type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;

export interface CanUrlDateListen {
  focusDate$: Observable<Date>
}

export type CanUrlDateListenCtor = Constructor<CanUrlDateListen> &
  AbstractConstructor<CanUrlDateListen>

export interface HasActivatedRoute {
  route: ActivatedRoute
}

export function mixinUrlDateListener<
  Base extends Constructor<HasActivatedRoute>
>(base: Base): CanUrlDateListenCtor & Base {
  return class extends base {

    focusDate$: Observable<Date>

    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args)

      // 1) access the injected ActivatedRoute service 
      // 2) map a query parameter to a Date object 
      // 3) expose it to the derived classes
      this.focusDate$ = this.route.queryParams.pipe(
        map((params) => new Date(params['date'])),
      )
    }
  }
}
```

This works great when only one mixin is applied:

```
const _DerivedBase = mixinUrlDateListener(class {
  constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) {}
})
```

[image]

But, when chaining mixins, the `route` property mysteriously becomes an array of all of the dependencies injected in the chain.

```
const _AnotherDerivedBase = mixinSearchable(mixinUrlDateListener(class {
  constructor(
    public route: ActivatedRoute,
    public overlay: Overlay,
    public injector: Injector
  ) {}
}))
```

[image]

I added the following workaround to access `ActivatedRoute` via the `args` parameter, but it seems like an anti-pattern to me:

```
// mixinUrlDateListener.constructor

const route: ActivatedRoute =
  args[0] instanceof ActivatedRoute
    ? args[0]
    : args[0].find((arg: any) => arg instanceof ActivatedRoute)

this.focusDate$ = route.queryParams.pipe(/* ... */)
```

**Is there a better way to do this or is accessing injected dependencies from a mixin an anti-pattern itself?**

Comment: I guess a class based approach is not ideal for a mixin/chaining approach. A more functional approach would probably make  more sense.

Comment: @MikeOne can you link me up to an example?

Comment: Not at the moment I’m afraid.. on mobile in a holiday home , no laptop, no wifi..

Comment: it looks like one of your mixins is causing this issue by calling `super(args)` instead of `super(...args)`

Comment: damn. that was it!